# Bash Script No Such File or Directory when Resolving Passed-in Arguments

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that looks like this:

```
if [ $# -eq 2 ]; then
    REDIS_HOME=$2
else
    if [ $# -eq 3 ]; then
        REDIS_HOME=$2
        PORTS=$3
    else
        REDIS_HOME="/usr/local/redis"
    fi
fi

case "$1" in
    start)
       if [ -z "$PORTS" ]; then
           cmd="$REDIS_HOME/bin/redis-server $REDIS_HOME/redis-6379.conf"
           $cmd
       else
           IFS=",";
           for port in $PORTS
           do
               cmd="$REDIS_HOME/bin/redis-server $REDIS_HOME/redis-$port.conf"
               $cmd
           done
       fi
    ;;
    *)
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

When I run the script with `my_script.sh start`, it works well by using the default redis home in the script. But when I ran it with `my_script.sh start /usr/local/redis 6379`, it says `"/usr/local/redis/bin/redis-server /usr/local/redis/redis-6379.conf" No such file or directory`.

Basically, I'm passing in the same `REDIS_HOME`, but I cannot figure out why the script cannot resolve the path if it's passed in as a parameter.

Comment: Paste your code in this site: https://www.shellcheck.net/.  You have a syntax error in your case.

Comment: Is that your full script?  You're missing a `fi` after the `else`.  Also a `;;` at the end of the `start` case.  If you fill in any missing parts it may be easier to help.

Comment: and no need to end your lines with `;`, Bash aint C :-)

Comment: @Nic3500 When you ask the `type` builtin to print a Bash function, it adds the semicolons by default.

Comment: @Nic3500. Thank you for pointing it out.  But my actual code doesn't have those syntax errors.  I just copy pasted part of it and made some minor modifications to serve as an example.

Comment: @dg99 Just fixed the errors. It's the same issue anyway since my actual script doesn't have those errors.

Comment: Well we debug what we see, not what we think you did :-)

Comment: What happens if you replace `$cmd` with `eval $cmd`?

Comment: I do not have reddis on my system, so I did a `echo $cmd`.  I copied your code, added `#!/bin/bash` on top and it ran ok.  The echo gave me this: `/usr/local/redis/bin/redis-server /usr/local/redis/redis-6379.conf`.  If I put something in $2 it uses it.

Comment: @Nic3500, Yeah, I have the `#!/bin/bash` as well. The evaluation of the command worked, I can see the whole command got printed in console.  It just complains No such file or directory.

Comment: So... did you check that the files *are* there or not?

Comment: @Nic3500  The files are there.  I posted the whole script just in case. So it can take 2 arguments, the second one being the port number.  I think something went wrong there.

Comment: Please try `eval $cmd` as I suggested.  It should resolve the issue.

Comment: I guess you learned how *not* to ask questions on SO :-)

Comment: Do you modify `$IFS` anywhere in the script?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I actually set `IFS=","`.  I just edited the script, you can see that line of code.  Does it make any difference?

Comment: @dg99.  Adding `eval` worked for me!  Can you briefly explain the difference? Thank you so much.

Comment: Variables are for data, not code generally.  See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 2):

`IFS=,` is causing the problem. When you do

```
$cmd
```

it uses `$IFS` to break the expansion of `$cmd` into words. Since space is not in `$IFS`, the space is not treated as a delimiter between the program name and the argument, so the entire result is treated as the program name. And of course it's not found.

I'm not sure why you need the `$cmd` variable in the first place. You can just do:

```
IFS=",";
for port in $PORTS
do
    $REDIS_HOME/bin/redis-server $REDIS_HOME/redis-$port.conf
done
```

Comment: I knew from experience that this was almost certainly the problem as soon as I saw the post (which was why I recommended `eval`), but recently I've been bitten by cases where two users run the same Bash, one sees a problem like the OP, and the other does not.  The users must have slightly different environments, but for the life of me I can't find those differences.  As a result I've lost all faith in what I thought I knew about Bash word-splitting and `IFS`, regardless of how many times I read Greg's Wiki.

Comment: @dg99 What's surprising to me is that `eval` resets `IFS` to the default while it's executing the command.